# How to make text fit inside a python curses textbox?

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I've tried many things attempting to make the text stay inside its borders but I can't find a way. Below is what I've already tried.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses
import textwrap

screen = curses.initscr()
screen.immedok(True)

try:
    screen.border(0)

    box1 = curses.newwin(20, 40, 6, 50)
    box1.immedok(True)
    text = "I want all of this text to stay inside its box. Why does it keep going outside its borders?"
    box1.box()
    box1.addstr(1, 0, textwrap.fill(text, 39))

    #box1.addstr("Hello World of Curses!")

    screen.getch()

finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first problem is that calling `box1.box()` *takes up space* in your box.  It uses up the top row, the bottom row, the first column, and the last column.  When you use `box1.addstr()` to put a string in a box, it starts at col 0, row 0, and so overwrites the box characters.  After creating your borders, your box only has 38 available characters per line.

I'm not a curses expert, but one way of resolving this is to create a new box *inside* `box1` that is inset by one character all the way around.  That is:

```
box2 = curses.newwin(18,38,7,51)
```

Then you can write your text into that box without overwriting the box drawing characters in `box1`.  It's also not necessary to call `textwrap.fill`; it appears that writing a string to a window with `addstr` automatically wraps the text.  In fact, calling `textwrap.fill` can interact badly with the window: if text wrap breaks a line at exactly the window width, you may end up with an erroneous blank line in your output.

Given the following code:

```
try:
    screen.border(0)

    box1 = curses.newwin(20, 40, 6, 50)
    box2 = curses.newwin(18,38,7,51)
    box1.immedok(True)
    box2.immedok(True)
    text = "I want all of this text to stay inside its box. Why does it keep going outside its borders?"
    text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
    text = "A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away, there lived a young man named Luke Skywalker."
    box1.box()
    box2.addstr(1, 0, textwrap.fill(text, 38))

    #box1.addstr("Hello World of Curses!")

    screen.getch()

finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Note that Thomas Dickey and I have posted essentially the same answer, although his uses `.derwin` to create a subwindow which is probably the better way of doing it.  Mine has pictures. Flip a coin :)

Answer (score 6):

The **box** is part of the **window**, and uses the same real estate as the text.  You can make a subwindow of the first window after drawing a box on the first window.  Then write your wrapped text in the subwindow.

Something like

```
box1 = curses.newwin(20, 40, 6, 50)
box1.immedok(True)
text = "I want all of this text to stay inside its box. Why does it keep going outside its borders?"
box1.box()
box1.refresh()
# derwin is relative to the parent window:
box2 = box1.derwin(18, 38, 1,1)
box2.addstr(1, 0, textwrap.fill(text, 39))
```

See the description of [`derwin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.derwin) in the reference.