# Why do forms and menus need two windows?

Tags: forms, menu, curses

The manpages `menu_win(3X)` and `form_win(3X)` say that the main window (set with `set_menu_win(MENU*, WINDOW*)` in menus) displays any title and border associated with the window. Why is this necessary? Wouldn't be one window for the actual forms/menus enough or does it have some purpose?

Comment: This (and similar) answers your question: [How to make text fit inside a python curses textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656335/how-to-make-text-fit-inside-a-python-curses-textbox)

Comment: It probably was done to simplify drawing the border (commonly done in curses using `box`) without having to redraw the inner window.

Comment: Well windows are cool, they let you overflow text and use "relative" coordinates, I would certainly use one window for decorations and a subwindow for the actual form/menu, but why do menus and forms want both of my windows? I should be responsible for the decorations and form/menu library should be responsible for their forms/menus.